# How to format an object of objects

Tags: javascript

I have this object

```js
myObject = {
  id: "44",
  name: "name",
  firstName: "fn",
  lastName: "tt",
  cars: [],
  houses: [],
  family: {}
}
```

I want to format this object to

```js
myObject = {
  person: {
    id: "44",
    name: "name",
    firstName: "fn",
    lastName: "tt"
  },
  cars: [],
  houses: [],
  family: {}
}
```

Is there anyway i can do this without using `delete`?

Comment: Dynamically or can it be done directly?

Comment: Your question doesn't show your attempt

Comment: I've tried with copying the object, delete the unwanted objects then reformat but it doesnt look clean

Comment: To answer your question... yes, it's possible to achieve this without using `delete`.

Comment: i prefer dynamic

Comment: @Ndx If it's dynamic, what is? The keys that should be nested in the `person` object, or the keys that should not be nested in the `person` object?

Comment: you're right there are no matching key between objects so it can be done dynamically. @messerbill solution works

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `destructuring`:

```js
const myObject = { id:"44", name:"name", firstName:"fn", lastName:"tt", cars: [], houses:[], family:{}}

const { houses, cars, family, ...rest } = myObject

const myNewObject = {
  person: rest,
  houses,
  cars,
  family
}
console.log(myNewObject)
```

Comment: Is `person: {...rest},` necessary? I am thinking since `rest` already is an object that comprises of all the remaining keys, we can use `person: rest`

Answer (score 1):

You can use destructuring assignments to decompose your object into variables and restructure them in a simple function.

```js
const format = (obj) => {
    const {id, name, firstName, lastName, ...props} = obj;
    return {person: {id, name, firstName, lastName}, ...props}
}

const formatted = format(myObject);

console.log (formatted)
```

```html
<script>
var myObject = { id:"44", name:"name", firstName:"fn", lastName:"tt", cars: [], houses:[], family:{}}
</script>
```

Comment: My understanding is OP wants to modify the original object, not clone it.

Comment: No need to destructure all properties, just those we don't want to hang onto. `const {id, name, firstName, lastName, ...props} = obj; return {...props, person: {id, name, firstName, lastName}};`

Comment: This would work but it isnt dynamic. this is a sample of an object. My current one has 20+ property. something dynamic would work better

Comment: @chelmertz Thanks, i didn't knew the spread rest operator is already supported.

Comment: @Ndx Can you post an example of your actual data and how you want to format it?

Answer (score 0):

You could create a new object and assign the properties to it:

```js
let obj = { id:"44", name:"name", firstName:"fn", lastName:"tt", cars: [], houses:[], family:{}}

//I want to format this object to
//myObject = { person: {id:"44", name:"name", firstName:"fn", lastName:"tt"}, cars: [], houses:[], family:{}}

let res =  {}

res.person = {id: obj.id, name: obj.name, firstName: obj.firstName, lastName: obj.lastName}
res.cars = obj.cars
res.houses = obj.houses
res.family = obj.family

console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can destructure what you need, put the rest into a variable `rest`, and then re-assign `myObject`:

```js
let myObject = {
  id: "44",
  name: "name",
  firstName: "fn",
  lastName: "tt",
  cars: [],
  houses: [],
  family: {}
}

const {id, name, firstName, lastName, ...rest } = myObject;

myObject = {
  person: { id, name, firstName, lastName },
  ...rest
}

console.log(myObject);
```